# How does 殳 resemble a hand holding a tool?

Tags: glyph-origin

After reading the etymology of [設](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%A8%AD), I read that of one of the underlying ideograms: [殳](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%AE%B3).

> Pictogram (*[象形](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%B1%A1%E5%BD%A2#Chinese)*) or Ideogrammic compound (*[會意](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%9C%83%E6%84%8F#Chinese)*): *[几](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%87%A0#Chinese)* + *[又](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%8F%88#Chinese)* – a hand holding a tool, hence activity.

1. How does 几 resemble a hand?
2. How does 又 resemble a tool? What tool is being referred to?

[This YouTube video](https://youtu.be/xDn7TMRtkaE?t=38) didn't assist.

[image]

Comment: 又 refers to the hand, not 几.

Comment: *Pro-tip*: Imgur automatically creates multiple files with varying image sizes [original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOqTi.jpg) [large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOqTil.jpg) [medium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOqTim.jpg) [small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOqTis.jpg).  The latter three are obtained by adding an `l`, `m` or `s` directly before `.jpg`.

Answer (score 4):

Slight correction, 「殳」 originally depicted a *hand* 「又」 holding a *spear/rod-like weapon/club*.

---

> <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
> [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
> [image: 殳]
> [乙](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)8520
> [合集21868](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=21868&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>商
> [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
> [image: 㱿]
> 亞殸斝
> [集成9161](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9161&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou)
> 金
> [image: 殳]
> 趞曹鼎
> [集成2784](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=2784&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
> 金
> [image: 毀]
> 鄂君啟車節
> [集成12110](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=12110&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
> [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
> [image: 殳]
> 效律45
> [睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd><kbd>今
> [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script)
> [image: 殳]</kbd>
>
> <sub>Forms 1, 3, 5, 6 are all 「殳」. Form 2 is the character 「㱿」. Form 4 is the character 「毀」. Take note of the right hand side of 「㱿」 and 「毀」, which both have 「殳」 as a component.</sub>

「殳」 originally depicted a [*hand* 「又」](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=20) holding a *spear, rod, or club-like weapon*, which now looks like 「几」. The original meaning of 「殳」, a kind of *weapon*, is now written as 「杸」.

---

As a character component giving a meaning hint, 「殳」 originally had something to do with *attacking* or *hitting*. For example,

- 「擊」 *to attack*
- 「殺」 *to kill*
- 「毀」 *to destroy, ruin*
- 「役」 *enslave* > *labour*
- 「聲」 *sound* (*ears* 耳 hearing *stone chimes* 声 *being struck* 殳)

Through semantic extension, it was also used as a marker for verb-like words or [morphemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morpheme), such as

- 「發」 (*to shoot arrows > emit*)
- 「設」 (*to establish*)

---

**References:**

- 季旭昇《說文新證》
- [小學堂](http://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)