# What is this glyph image for 父 representing?

Tags: glyph-origin

I am trying to visualise this image for 父. What exactly is this image ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

| 時期 字體 | 字形 | 參考資料 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty) [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script) | [image: 父] | [乙](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)405 [合集19941](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=19941&jgwfl=) |
| 商 [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions) | [image: 父] | 父癸方鼎 [集成1275](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=1275&jgwfl=) |
| [西周](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Zhou) 金 | [image: 父] | 父辛簋 [集成3060](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=3060&jgwfl=) |
| [春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period) 金 | [image: 父] | 魯大宰父 [集成3987](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=3987&jgwfl=) |
| [戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state)) [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips) | [image: 父] | 126 [包山竹簡](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E5%8C%85%E5%B1%B1%E6%A5%9A%E7%B0%A1) |
| [西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Western_Han) [隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script) | [image: 父] | 86 定縣竹簡 |
| [東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han) 隸 | [image: 父] | 北海相景君 |
| [楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_script) | [image: 父] |  |

「父」 (*father*) depicts a [*hand* 「又」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=20) holding a *rod*, likely as a symbol of the household disciplinarian, which is traditionally the *father*.

The shape 「父」 is connected to the shapes [「攴・攵」](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=31257) and [「殳」](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/39055/how-does-%E6%AE%B3-resemble-a-hand-holding-a-tool), both pictures of a *hand* holding a *hitting implement*, and both meaning *to hit, strike*.

---

**References:**

- 何琳儀《戰國古文字典：戰國文字聲系》
- [小學堂字形演變](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian)
- [國學大師](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/)

  - [郭沫若《甲骨文合集》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/jgwhj/)
  - [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: (After watching the episode of 字裡尋根 that explained the origin of 父 and 斧, I completely changed my answer)

[image]

父 is a symbol of a hand holding a tool/weapon. (to protect and provide is the father's duty)

*It is the phonic component of the character 斧 (axe); 斤 was a shape of the knife, adding the phonic component 父 made the character 斧.*

[image: 父]

In ancient time,  the father of the family was the one handling tool/weapon, and this tool/weapon is most likely an axe.

Comment: Is this axe or rod or stick ? Can you visualise that old instrument? Are the two sides hands? Or it was part of instrument?

Comment: I thought the axe's head and the handle is clearly illustrated

Comment: A visualization could help.  We'd probably expect something more like a `Γ` ([capital Gamma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma) from the Greek alphabet), but instead it looks more like a `T` ([capital T](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T) from the English alphabet).  Perhaps it's like [the one in this picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:%E5%A4%8F%E6%A1%80%E5%83%8F.png)?  Though a lot of us may've been looking for an axe more like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:An_axe_labelled-2edit.svg).

Comment: @Nat Indeed. Wood-cutting axes are [斤](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=134); battle-axes are [戌](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=383) or [戉](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=5462). 父 being an axe lacks paleographic evidence; although a rather well-known scholar once made this argument, it isn't an orthodox POV in the field.